# UDP SO_TIMESTAMP in windows

Tags: windows, udp, timestamp

I want to implement the SO_TIMESTAMP in windows for UDP packets , so that we can get the arrival time of the UDP packet at the kernel Queue.
Please tell the equivalent in windows C++ to get to SO_TIMESTAMP equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered this:

> Receive timestamps
>
> You configure receive timestamp reception through the SIO_TIMESTAMPING
> IOCTL. Use that IOCTL to enable receive timestamp reception. When you
> receive a datagram using the LPFN_WSARECVMSG (WSARecvMsg) function,
> its timestamp (if available) is contained in the SO_TIMESTAMP control
> message.
>
> SO_TIMESTAMP (0x300A) is defined in mstcpip.h. The control message
> data is returned as a UINT64.

See [Windows Developer: Winsock timestamping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/winsock-timestamping) and [Windows Developer: Packet timestamping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/iphlp/packet-timestamping)

[Greyware Automation Products, Inc](https://www.greyware.com/kb/kb2019.708.asp) explains some details in their Knowldegebase article "FAQ: Domain Time and NDIS Software Timestamps":

They state that starting with Windows 10 (version 1803 or later), and Windows Server 2019, Microsoft introduced kernel-level support for UDP packet software timestamping at the NDIS layer of the TCP/IP network stack.

Software timestamping must be enabled on appropriate NICs for example by this Powershell script: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SoftwareTimestamping/1.0

IOCTLs and structures are defined within mstcpip.h of Windows 10 SDK version 2104 minimum!